# .NET CF using code to select images from project path

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, imagelist

the project has a folder that stores images that would be used, say"project\Symbols". then I want to create a ImageList object and add some of those images into it.

```
public partial class us_var
    {
        #region "Static variables"
        public static string SD = @"Storage Card\";
        public static string[] tables = {"DataRecord","EventRecord","AlarmRecord"};
        public static Size _sysSize = new Size(1024,600);
        public static Size _logoSize = new Size(80,80);
        public static Size _titSize = new Size(5,1025);
        public static ImageList iL = new ImageList();       
        #endregion
    }
public partial class us_ini
    {
        public void iL_ini()
        {
            us_var.iL.Images.Add(Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\Symbols\logo.png"));
        }
    }
```

then I got an error "System.Drawing.Image" doesn't contain "FromFile" define.

And I know the reason is because .NET CF doesn't support such quote. So how can I use code to select images from a specified folder in .NET CF?
anyone has solutions?
Thank you guys!

Comment: `new Bitmap(file_path)`

Comment: that helps，no errors at least.